# why regular expression not working in ie?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

Hello all i have one regular expression which is working in all browsers except IE. I don't know why please help.

```js
sep = 9999999999;
rgx = new RegExp('(\\d+)(\\d{'+sep+'})');
```

sep variable has dynamic numbers. And **SyntaxError: Syntax error in regular expression** error is occurring in IE.

Comment: Have you tried stripping down pattern to pinpoint error place? Like reducing `sep` to `1`?

Comment: Just to confirm - I'm reproducing it in IE11 via `new RegExp('(\\d+)(\\d{9999999999})');`

Comment: @VLAZ yes same pattern, but sep is dynamic

Comment: @Justinas sorry i don't understand what are you saying?

Comment: @user3458271 Instead of `9999999999` put `1` or `12`

Comment: What kind of data that contain more than 10 billion digits are you processing?

Comment: Can you please inform us, What are the chances that sep will contain 9999999999 this value? Did you got the similar issues with other values? I think this is the limitation of IE but did not got any document which can confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Going to hazard a wild guess here, that since it's unlikely the regex engine would actually handle a ten-billion-character-long string, the numeric quantifiers are limited in the number of digits they can contain.

Try one fewer nine until it works.

But seriously, ten billion digits?

Comment: yes because it is counting and putting separators & symbols in numbers .

Comment: Okay so I miscounted and it's 10 billion, not 10 trillion, but even so... such a string would require 10GB of RAM to store, and much more to actually process via regex.

Comment: i am just getting numbers from client , so ram is not my issue, and even it is working in all other browser not in IE only

Comment: If it helps - taking off one digit from the the repetition makes the regex compile correctly. At least on IE11 - I've not checked the other ones. I do agree that the number of digits seems excessive. If you're trying to extract a number that long from input, I really wonder what the total input looks like, as it would be at least 10 **Giga**bytes. I find it hard to imagine that browsers don't choke trying to read that amount of data.

Comment: yes removing one digit helped and worked ,but i have to test is properly as numbers are not from my side.

Comment: @user3458271 likely because atom repetition length is stored in a 32-bit integer. My guess is that 2147483647 is the largest value you can use (at least if IE's regex parser is anything [like the one in .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.RegularExpressions/src/System/Text/RegularExpressions/RegexParser.cs#L1391))